# grails 3 taglib, html builder and createLInk

Tags: grails, taglib

Is it possible in grails 3 to create a taglib using createLink and HTMLBuilder. I tried with :

```
def buttonTaglib = { attrs, body ->
        def mb = new groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder(out)
        mb.button(type: "button", class: "btn btn-success") {
            g.createLink(controller: 'test', action: 'show', id: 1) { mkp.yield "buttonTaglib" }
        }
    }
```

and

```
def buttonTaglib2 = { attrs, body ->
        def mb = new groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder(out)
        out << g.createLink(controller:"test", action:"show") << mb.button(type: "button", class: "btn btn-success") { "buttonSimple" }
    }
```

without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would your typical out used by standard suffice, if so it's as easy as this:

```
def buttonTaglib2 = { attrs, body ->
        out << """
<a href="${g.createLink(controller:"test", action:"show")}" class="btn btn-success">Test</a>
"""
    }
```

You can also just render a template and pass params or attrs to the tempalate. Then process your values as you would normally from controller to view.

Answer (score 0):

This one is working for me:

```
def button = { attrs, body ->
        def mb = new groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder(out)
        out << link(controller: attrs.controller, action: attrs.action, id: attrs.id, params: attrs.params ) {
            mb.button(type: attrs.type, class: attrs.class) {
                mkp.yield attrs.name
            }
        }
}
```